# ordering of agg names not retained in the response

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

i am executing a elastic query and reading the response inside java code using REST calls.
when i read the response, order of fields - 200, 204, 4xx, 5xx are not returned in the order in the response.

find below sample request placed

```
GET appl-activity*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_daterange": {
      "range": {
        "field": "Date",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": "Fri Oct 23 02:54:26 2020 -0400",
            "to": "Mon Oct 26 05:54:26 2020 -0400"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "byapplication": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "application.keyword",
            "size": 1000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "by200": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "200"
              }
            },
            "by204": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "204"
              }
            },
            "by4xx": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "4xx"
              }
            },
            "by5xx": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "5xx"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

response returned :-

```
{
  "took" : 35,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1173,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "group_by_daterange" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Fri Oct 23 06:54:26 2020 +0000-Mon Oct 26 09:54:26 2020 +0000",
          "from" : 1.603436066E12,
          "from_as_string" : "Fri Oct 23 06:54:26 2020 +0000",
          "to" : 1.603706066E12,
          "to_as_string" : "Mon Oct 26 09:54:26 2020 +0000",
          "doc_count" : 30,
          "byapplication" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "SITE",
                "doc_count" : 20,
                "by4xx" : {
                  "value" : 1.0
                },
                "by5xx" : {
                  "value" : 0.0
                },
                "by204" : {
                  "value" : 0.0
                },
                "by200" : {
                  "value" : 5342.0
                }
              },
              {
                "key" : "MOBILE",
                "doc_count" : 10,
                "by4xx" : {
                  "value" : 0.0
                },
                "by5xx" : {
                  "value" : 0.0
                },
                "by204" : {
                  "value" : 0.0
                },
                "by200" : {
                  "value" : 5635.0
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

i am expecting the response codes in the same order that is there in the request. please help me??

```
{
  "key": "MOBILE",
  "doc_count": 10,
  "by200": {
    "value": 5635
  },
  "by204": {
    "value": 0
  },
  "by4xx": {
    "value": 0
  },
  "by5xx": {
    "value": 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike arrays, JSON dictionaries aren't guaranteed any order. This means there's no specification which would force ElasticSearch or any other JSON-in/JSON-out interface to retain the input order.

*While that's unfortunate, some systems (e.g. [stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object)) go the extra mile to alphabetically sort the response keys just before returning to the client.*

---

Having said that, I used to approach this problem by prepending an alphanumeric char combination to the agg key name based on the order I wanted:

```
{
  "1__myAggName": { ... },
  "2__myAggName": { ... },
   ...
}
```

Then on the client side I'd trivially sort the agg keys and ditch the prefixes.

**But these days I tend to use [aggregation metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/agg-metadata.html) where I put the order and other info. This greatly improved transparency and readability of all my post-processing steps**:

```
{
  ...
  "byapplication": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "application.keyword",
      "size": 1000
    },
    "aggs": {
      "by200": {
        "meta": {       <--
          "index": 0
        },
        "sum": {
          "field": "200"
        }
      },
      "by204": {
        "meta": {      <--
          "index": 1
        },
        "sum": {
          "field": "204"
        }
      },
      "by4xx": {
        "meta": {
          "index": 2
        },
        "sum": {
          "field": "4xx"
        }
      },
      "by5xx": {
        "meta": {
          "index": 3
        },
        "sum": {
          "field": "5xx"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```